# Why is my donut so grainy (cycles rendering)?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

So I am doing the donut tutorial and when I render my image is super grainy.
I looked at all the other answers but the interface looks different from the one I have and I am not sure what to change.
My GPU is GeForce GTX 1650.
[image]

I increased the Render and Viewport value but it didn't change much. Even at 5000 viewports, it's grainy. Here are the settings for the image above. Is this the best I can expect with my GPU?
[image: Settings]

Answer (score 5):

The noise or grain, in the image, is a can be decreased by two means.

**First: increasing the samples**

The "Render and Viewport value" is in fact the number of samples that Cycles are going to perform. The viewport refers to how many samples are done in the viewport rendering, and render refers to how many samples are done when actually rendering the final image.It could be that you increase the viewport samples and didn't increase the render.

In general the more samples the better, but you also have diminishing returns, for example, the difference between 10 and 100 samples is a lot, but between 100 and 200 not that much by comparison. also the more samples the longer the render is going to be.

**Second: Denoising**

In this method, you do a moderate amount of samples and add a denoiser after the render. There a couple of ways you can do this in Blender.

- the first way can read more [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html)
- and [here](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-intel-denoiser-in-blender/) you can check another way
  to denoise

the second way of denoising requires compositing in Blender, so if you are just beginning it may seem to complicate, so you may want to use the first denoising method.

as for the question "Is this the best I can expect with my GPU?" you are not technically limited to a certain quality by hardware, it just means you are going to have to wait for more for the same quality, but if you have the time you can do it. a GTX 1650 is pretty good.

hope this helps, good luck with blender :)

Comment: Very good explanation. I wonder why Blender does not have a standard easy and fast way to automatically setup the denoising nodes. It all has to be done manually, which is a bother.  There used to be a earlier denoiser that you could just switch on, very simple.

Comment: The denoiser that you could just switch on, is still there and you can still use it, the compositing one is a new one and another option, my guess is the is base on a compositing workflow, and that's why the put it there, also it gives the user more control in the compositing.