# Following a blender tutorial and rendering is grainy

Tags: modeling, rendering, shadows

So I just recently started using blender as my friends started using it to make models for vrchat, so I decided to learn it as well, I was following the donut tutorial by blender guru but as I came to the rendering step I noticed that my render was much more grainy than his even though we had the same render numbers, any ideas? I tried increasing it further but noticed no difference at all. might the numbers have changed through the updates so they are not the same for the same quality or something?

Specs

GTX 2070 Super

16gb RAM

AMD Radeon 3700x

750w power supply

Comment: Denoising feature needs to be used, Andrew (blenderguru) explains how to do it in one of the episodes....

Comment: Can you post the two renders? Or at least yours so we can have a look? How many samples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my donut so grainy (cycles rendering)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186736/why-is-my-donut-so-grainy-cycles-rendering)